# Qu'est-ce que ça te fait ? / Qu'est-ce que ça peut te faire ?

Tags: sens

Est-ce qu'il y aurait une différence de sens entre :

1) Qu'est-ce que ça te fait ?

et

2) Qu'est-ce que ça peut te faire ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La première formule semble demander une réponse qui exprime un sentiment, une sensation, en retour :

> Qu'est-ce que ça te fait si j'appuie là ?

La seconde semble demander une raison pour que l'action puisse déclencher un sentiment ou une sensation :

> Qu'est-ce que ça peut te faire si j'enlève mes chaussures ?

Comment: En insistant sur le fait que la 2ème phrase est un brin ironique/rhétorique... La réponse fortement sous entendue est "Cela ne me concerne effectivement pas", dans le sens qu'il n'y a aucune raison que l'action décrite ne dérange la personne à qui on parle...

Answer (score 7):

Pas tant une différence de sens qu'une différence légère d'usage. "Qu'est-ce que ça te fait?" est généralement suivi d'une condition/d'un contexte ("Qu'est-ce que ça te fait si je trompe ma femme? C'est pas de tes affaires!"), tandis que "Qu'est-ce que ça peut te faire?" est plus souvent utilisé comme phrase entière. Le sens reste toutefois le même.

Au Québec, le #1 est plus commun dans la langue parlée, mais le #2 est plus commun à l'écrit.

Comment: En France, la phrase "Qu'est-ce que ça te fait si je trompe ma femme? C'est pas de tes affaires!" semble moins utilisée (à l'oral) que "Qu'est-ce que ça **peut** te fai**re** si je trompe ma femme? C'est pas de tes affaires!".

Comment: @Random C'est ce que je croyais aussi! Au niveau des dialogues/de la langue familière, le français écrit du Québec est souvent calqué du français parlé de France. Culturellement, les Québécois ont tendance à associer "bon français" ou "français universel" avec le français de France, outre ses anglicismes et son dialecte local.